# Automapper 6.1.1 Exception using MemberList.Source: Unmapped members were found

Tags: c#, automapper

I'm getting the following error in Automapper:

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
For no matching constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of the constructor parameters
```

Configuration looks like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ArticleViewModel, Article>(MemberList.Source)
    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id);
```

Normally I would solve it like `.ForMember(x => x.NoMapProp, opt => opt.Ignore())` but since I'm using `MemberList.Source` I can't reach the property with ForMember. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easy, solved like this:

```
cfg.CreateMap<ArticleViewModel, Article>(MemberList.Source)
    .EqualityComparison((src, dst) => src.Id == dst.Id)
    .ForSourceMember(x => x.NoMapProp, opt => opt.Ignore());
```